# What component of android xml is this?

Tags: android, xml, listview, cardview

Hi I am developing an android app and I want to add a similar component that I found in another app this is the structure:

[image]

So I want to make something like this but I can't figure out what components of xml android to use I was thinking of a CardView with a ListView inside or use  a table layout instead but I dont know if that's the right choice because it has to be dynamic, when I tap the + button I have to add a new row or when I tap the - the last row has to disappear also the weight and reps elements are text field's for the user to input data. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: there are plenty of ways to achieve this, from standard components to third party libraries. You may want to be more specific on what you've tried, and what specifically didn't work for you

Comment: @TooManyEduardos Hi, I'm just looking for the best way to approach this problem, I haven't starting coding yet and I'm not looking for a coded answer I'm just seeking for advice in what approach could I use to solved this problem cause I haven't figure it out myself.

Comment: That's the point. There is no "best answer" without trying something. There's no magical component or library that makes pretty, slick, and updated UI out of the box that matches a single case. This example could be a complex custom UI because the developer decided to reuse the elements throughout the app, so it requires a theme, spacers, and other fillers. There's really no way to guide you without having you try something first and see where you end up. This could be just a super simple button and a few textviews with some pretty graphics...it's just too hard to help you without a baseline